# Software to recover old Skype chat logs?

Tags: open-source, data-recovery, skype

I am trying to recover old Skype chat logs from 5 years ago. Nirsoft's old app for this doesn't seem to work. Does anyone have other suggestions?

Comment: If Nirsoft Skype log view cannot see those, most likely your local chat database no longer contain such chats.